# Update column with increasing value using a single statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a third-party application that has been migrated from a much earlier version to the current release, and during the migration a new column has been added to the database.  This column represents the external test case identifier.  There is a unique identifier in the table for the test case record, which is hidden from the user.  When a new version of the test case is created, a new record is added to the table.  There is obviously a new id, but the external identifier remains the same so it appears to the end user that this is the same test case.  Not my model, but fair enough.

During the migration process, that column was added and now all the test cases look like they have an id of zero.  Oops.  Well, almost all, because a few new cases have been added through the GUI and they have the correct number.  And to boot one of the test cases actually has a second version.  I've fixed that record so it has a valid external id.

Here's a snapshot of the relevant bit of my table:

```
mysql> select id, version, tc_external_id from tcversions order by id limit 5;
+------+---------+----------------+
| id   | version | tc_external_id |
+------+---------+----------------+
| 9454 |       1 |              0 |
| 9455 |       1 |              5 |
| 9456 |       1 |              0 |
| 9457 |       1 |              0 |
| 9458 |       1 |              0 |
+------+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.33 sec)
```

For those of you familiar with the database, yes, this is TestLink 1.9.3.  It's a migrated database from a modified 1.7.4 system that we inherited.

I'm looking for a MySQL UPDATE statement that will let me update the tc_external_id such that each record gets a monotonically increasing number without having to resort to writing a separate bash/perl/whatever script that executes N number of updates.  So the result would look something like the following:

```
mysql> select id, version, tc_external_id from tcversions order by id limit 5;
+------+---------+----------------+
| id   | version | tc_external_id |
+------+---------+----------------+
| 9454 |       1 |              6 |
| 9455 |       1 |              5 |
| 9456 |       1 |              7 |
| 9457 |       1 |              8 |
| 9458 |       1 |              9 |
+------+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.33 sec)
```

Is this possible?  My SQL foo is obviously not up to the task, and I'm happy to RTM if someone can point me to the right FM.

**Edit: Co-worker came up with the following solution**

A co-worker of mine provided me with the solution, which is quite nasty if I do say so myself.  The formatting is mine, he did it as one long line.  Gah.  Flame away, but it did work.

```
REPLACE INTO tcversions 
  SELECT @r := id as id, 
         @r1 := version as version, 
         @r2 := summary as summary, 
         @r3 := importance as importance, 
         @r4 := author_id as author_id, 
         @r5 := creation_ts as creation_ts,
         @r6 := updater_id as updater_id, 
         @r7 := modification_ts as modification_id, 
         @r8 := active as active, 
         @r9 := is_open as is_open, 
         @r10 := execution_type as execution_type, 
         @c := @c + 1 as tc_external_id, 
         @r12 := layout as layout, 
         @r13 := status as status, 
         @r14 := preconditions as preconditions 
  FROM 
    (SELECT @r := '', 
            @r1 := '', 
            @r2 := '', 
            @r3 := '', 
            @r4 := '', 
            @r5 := '', 
            @r6 := '', 
            @r7 := '', 
            @r8 :='', 
            @r9 := '', 
            @r10 := '', 
            @r11 := '', 
            @r12 := '', 
            @r13 := '', 
            @r14 := '',  
            @c := max(tcversions.tc_external_id) from tcversions ) rc, 
    (SELECT id,
            version, 
            summary, 
            importance, 
            author_id, 
            creation_ts, 
            updater_id, 
            modification_ts, 
            active, 
            is_open, 
            execution_type, 
            tc_external_id, 
            layout, 
            status, 
            preconditions 
     FROM tcversions  WHERE tc_external_id = 0  ORDER BY id) k;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE tcversions SET tc_external_id = @id := IF( ISNULL( @id ), 1, @id + 1 )
    WHERE id = 0;
```

you might want to replace that 1 (beginning value of @id) with one after the highest tc_external_id you already have from new inserts.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work.  The query had to be modified to change the where clause to be 'WHERE tc_external_id = 0' (the original was trying to set the one tcversion record with the actual id of zero, not the external id of zero) and I changed the start value to 6.  The result was tc_external_id was set to 6 for all rows.

Answer (score 1):

For reference

I found the answer [here](http://makandracards.com/makandra/1733-how-to-update-a-mysql-column-with-ascending-numbers) :

```
SET @id = 5;
UPDATE tcversions
  SET tc_external_id = (SELECT @id := @id + 1)
  WHERE tc_external_id=0
  ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: This is the right answer, tested and accepted! (+1).

Comment: How to do the same in postgresql?

Answer (score 0):

This somehow looks related to a top10 query. Sketch using SQlite:

```
sqlite> select a.id, a.version, count(*)
        from tcversions a, tcversions b
        where a.id >= b.id
        group by a.id;
9454|1|1
9455|1|2
9456|1|3
9457|1|4
```

The question is how to update your table now ;-)